# PowerBi Desktop - Scatter Chart > Y-Axis Constant Line: Need to disappear the line when the resultant value is null

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Program: PowerBi Desktop
Visualization: Scatter/Dot
Problem Description:

- I am visualizing time series measurements of certain attributes using a scatter plot. I wanted to place Upper and Lower Limits, so I am using the function "Y-Axis Constant Line" to fetch data from a separate column which stores minimum and maximum values for that attribute.
- The visualization works fine until I find cases where the field value of my column "MAX limit" is null. In this case, PowerBi still assigns the limit line as y=0 and plots it under the Minimum limit line. This gives a wrong interpretation that points are not in limit.
- I need to find a way for the visualization to not plot the limit line when value is null.

[See Image: Scatter Plot when MAX LIMIT Table has null values (shown in Green).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2IvP.jpg)

I color coded the line to show MIN LIMIT as Red and MAX Limit as Green. When MAX LIMIT Table has all null values, it is interpreted as 0.

In an attempt to fix it, I tried using a DAX measure to consider the y value as BLANK() (see below) since I read somewhere that line will not be plotted when BLANK() is thrown into the line generator, but it didn't work.

`LINE-MAX = IF(ISBLANK(MAX('TABLE'[MAX LIMIT])), BLANK(), MAX('TABLE'[MAX LIMIT]))`